# Django DRF serializer with many=true missuses the respective validate()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have run into the following problem:

There are 2 serializers CreateSerializer(child) and BulkCreateSerializer(parent).
They are connected via list_serializer_class.
I have overridden create() and validate() methods for both serializers and expect them to trigger respectively on whether a single instance is coming via POST or a list of instances.

However, when I am sending a post request with a list of instances serializer does switch to many=true but uses validate() that belongs to child CreateSerializer instead of dedicated BulkCreateSerializer, which runs me into errors of course.

[image: Example when I post list of items:]

So my question is, what could be the logic under the hood, that prevents my serializers to distribute the items for validation respectively? And how to make it work that way?

serializers.py

```
class RecipeStepDraftBulkCreateSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    
    def validate(self, data):
        print("bulk validate")
        new_step_numbers = [s.get('step_number') for s in data]
        if None in new_step_numbers:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("step_number filed is required")
        if new_step_numbers != list(set(new_step_numbers)):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Wrong order of step_number(s) supplied")
        try:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=self.context.get('recipe_id'))
            existing_steps = recipe.recipe_steps.get_queryset().all()
            if existing_steps:
                ex_step_numbers = [s.step_number for s in existing_steps]
                if new_step_numbers[0] != ex_step_numbers[-1] + 1:
                   raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    f"The next first supplied step_number must be: {ex_step_numbers[-1] + 1}") 
                steps_combined = ex_step_numbers + new_step_numbers
                if steps_combined != list(set(steps_combined)): 
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(f"Wrong order of step_number(s) supplied")  
            return data   
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Recipe under provided id doesn't exist.")    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=self.context.get('recipe_id'))
        for step in validated_data:
            step['recipe'] = recipe
            RecipeStep.objects.create(**step)
        return validated_data                

class RecipeStepDraftCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeStep 
        fields = [ 
            'id',
            'step_number',
            'step_image',
            'instruction',
            'tip']  
        list_serializer_class = RecipeStepDraftBulkCreateSerializer
    
    def validate(self, data):
        print("single validate")
        if not data.get("step_number"):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("step_number field is required.")
        try:
            recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=self.context.get('recipe_id'))
            existing_steps = recipe.recipe_steps.get_queryset().all()
            if existing_steps:
                ex_step_numbers = [s.step_number for s in existing_steps]
                if data["step_number"] != ex_step_numbers[-1] + 1:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    f"The next first supplied step_number must be: {ex_step_numbers[-1] + 1}") 
            if data["step_number"] != 1:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(f"Wrong step_number. 1 expected, got {data['step_number']}")        
            return data
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Recipe under provided id doesn't exist.")
                      

    def create(self, validated_data):
        recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=self.context.get('recipe_id'))
        validated_data['recipe'] = recipe
        step = RecipeStep.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return step
```

views.py

```
class DraftsRecipeStepsCreateView(APIView):
    
    serializer_class = RecipeStepDraftCreateSerializer  

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        print(f'DATA IS LIST: {isinstance(request.data, list)}')
        
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data, 
            many=isinstance(request.data, list), 
            context={
                'request': request,
                'recipe_id': kwargs.get('recipe_id')})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()   
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Just to confirm, `many=isinstance(request.data, list)` is true?

Comment: @bdbd Yes! on the screenshot I am posting a list of items, it identifies as True, but falls into single CreateSerializer

Answer (score 2):

The code that explains this behavior can be found [**`here`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L597-L653). It describes how a list serializer runs validations (the `run_validation` method).

Based on that, the list serializer first validates each child serializer as seen in the `to_internal_value` implementation:

```
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ...
        for item in data:
            try:
                validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
            except ValidationError as exc:
                errors.append(exc.detail)
            else:
                ret.append(validated)
                errors.append({})
        ...
```

before running its own list validate:

```
    def run_validation(self, data=empty):
        ...
        value = self.to_internal_value(data) # <-- children validation first
        try:
            self.run_validators(value) # <-- then the list validation
        ...
```

I tried this out with the below serializer:

```
class MyModelListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        print('mymodel list validate')
        return attrs


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = MyModelListSerializer

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print('mymodel validate')
        return attrs
```

using some sample data, and then validating:

```
somedata = [
    {
        "data": "1",
    },
    {
        "data": "2",
    }
]
s = MyModelSerializer(data=somedata, many=True); s.is_valid();
```

The output I get is then consistent on what the source suggests:

```
mymodel validate
mymodel validate
mymodel list validate
```

In your case I suspect `print("bulk validate")` did not trigger because there were problems in validating the child serializers causing the list serializer to not be run anymore.